# VBA, Selenium findelements and click or submit not working

Tags: vba, selenium, xpath, click

I'm trying to get selenium to click elements but nothing happend, i tried using xpath, name, text but not successfull
here is this element:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="startProcess('QC inspector creates inspection report');">QC inspector create inspection report</a>
```

xpath

```html
//*[@id="CustomHTML0"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/a
```

here is my code:

```html
Dim Crn As Selenium.WebElements
Set Crn = Bot.FindElementsByLinkText("QC inspector create inspection report", timeout:=5000)
Crn(1).Submit
```

or

```html
Dim Crn As Selenium.WebElements
Set Crn = Bot.FindElementsByXpath("//*[@id="CustomHTML0"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/a", timeout:=5000)
Crn(1).Submit
```

please help me, or point out where i went wrong
Thank you very much
Here is more code:

```html
<table border="0"><tbody><tr><td valign="top" width="200px"><font size="+1">Master Maintenance</font></td><td><a href="/teamworks/executeServiceByName?processApp=QCINSP&amp;serviceName=QA_COL-Vendor%20Factory%20Maintenance">Vendor Factory Maintenance</a></td></tr><tr><td valign="top" width="200px"><font size="+1">Enquiry</font></td><td><a href="/teamworks/executeServiceByName?processApp=QCINSP&amp;serviceName=QA_COL-QA%20user%20inquiries%20inspection%20report">QA user inquiries inspection report</a></td></tr><tr><td valign="top" width="200px"><font size="+1"></font></td><td><a href="/teamworks/executeServiceByName?processApp=QCINSP&amp;serviceName=QA_COL-QA%20user%20inquiries%20inspection%20report%20eConnect2">QA user inquiries inspection report eConnect2</a></td></tr><tr><td valign="top" width="200px"><font size="+1">Update</font></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="startProcess('QC inspector creates inspection report');">QC inspector create inspection report</a></td></tr><tr><td valign="top" width="200px"><font size="+1"></font></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="startProcess('Vendor creates inspection report');">Vendor creates inspection report</a></td></tr><tr><td valign="top" width="200px"><font size="+1"></font></td><td><a href="/teamworks/executeServiceByName?processApp=QCINSP&amp;serviceName=QA_COL-Vendor%20create%20inspection%20requisition">Vendor create inspection requisition</a></td></tr><tr><td valign="top" width="200px"><font size="+1"></font></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="startProcess('VA inspector creates correlation report');">VA inspector create correlation inspection report</a></td></tr><tr><td valign="top" width="200px"><font size="+1"></font></td><td><a href="/teamworks/executeServiceByName?processApp=QCINSP&amp;serviceName=VA%20inspector%20revise%20correlation%20report">VA supervisor revise approved correlation inspection report</a></td></tr><tr><td valign="top" width="200px"><font size="+1">Enquiry</font></td><td><a href="/teamworks/executeServiceByName?processApp=QCINSP&amp;serviceName=QA_COL-QA%20user%20inquiries%20correlation%20report">QA user inquiries correlation inspection report</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: What is the error you get? Is this path enclosed in an iframe? One line of HTML is not helping here. Please post more HTML code or if it is ok, share the website url to inspect.

Comment: Thanks for reply this path enclosed in an iframe , nothing happend, code running to end, no error appear. here is more code

Comment: If the path is in iframe, have switched to iframe first, before locating the desired element?